# prove problem 12.1 in a probabilistic theory of pattern recognition

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

I try to prove **Problem 12.1** in [A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387946184) by Luc Devroye. I follow the hint provided in the book.

> If $Z$ is non-negative r.v. satisfying $P\{Z > t \} \leq c e^{-2 nt^2}$, then $E\{Z^2\}\leq \frac{ \log(ce)}{2n}$

Hint:

1. $E[Z^2] = \int_0^{\infty} P\{Z^2>t\}dt$
2. $\int_0^\infty=\int_0^u+\int_u^\infty$
3. bound the first integral by $u$, and bound the second integral by exponential inequality
4. Fine u minimizing the upper bound

When I follow the second step, I try to break $P\{Z^2>t\}$ into $P\{Z>\sqrt{t}\}+P\{Z<-\sqrt{t}\}$. Then, $P\{Z<-\sqrt{t}\}$ should be zero.Thus, $P\{Z \leq \sqrt{t} \} \leq ce^{-2nt}$. Finally, I get $E[Z^2] \leq \frac{c}{2n}$. It doesn't match the right result. Where should I correct in order to achieve the right way?

Answer (score 3):

You used the exponential bound on the whole interval $[0,\infty)$. Apart from this bound, you also have the trivial bound  $P[Z^2>t]\leq 1$, which turns out to be better than the exponential  on some regions. For this reason, you need to partition $[0,\infty)$ accordingly and take advantage of both:

\begin{align}E[Z^2]&=\int_0^u P[Z^2>t]dt+\int_u^\infty P[Z^2>t]dt\\
&\leq \int_0^u 1dt+\int_u^\infty ce^{-2nt}dt \\
&= u+\frac{c}{2n}e^{-2nu}.\end{align}

Set $f(u)=u+\frac{c}{2n}e^{-2nu}$. It is easy to see that $f$ has a minimum at $u_0=\frac{\ln c}{2n}$ with $f(u_0)=\frac{\ln ce}{2n}.$ Since $E[Z^2]\leq f(u)$ for all $u$, we also have that $E[Z^2]\leq f(u_0)$, as we wanted.